# Passing parameter between Views to display information

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On my asp.net mvc website I want users to be able to click the book button within my events table and then be directed to a view which has a list of the tickets available for this event and be able to click another button to add each type of ticket to their basket/order. However I am having difficulty implementing this. I am unable to get the EventID (primary key of event) to pass from the table, when they click the book button in the table within the Index view, to the next Ticket booking View in order to retrieve the tickets which have a corresponding EventID (foreign key of ticket). Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck on this for ages.

Here are my Event and Ticket Models

```
 public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TicketsAvailable { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
    //navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Ticket { get; set; }

}

 public class Ticket
{
   public int TicketID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [ForeignKey("Event")]
   //foreign key
    public int EventID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Description { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public float Price { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Event Index model

```
<table class="pure-table pure-table horizontal">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Book Event</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var events in Model)
    {
        <tr class="even">
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => events.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => events.Date)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => events.Location)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => events.Description)</td>

            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Book", "Book", new { id = events.EventID     })</td>
        </tr>
    }
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is my Ticket Booking View

```
@model Site.Models.Ticket
<head>
<title>Order</title>

</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
   <tr>
       <th>Description</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Add</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach(Site.Models.Ticket t in ViewBag.listProducts)
   {
   <tr>
       <td>@t.Description</td>
       <td>@t.Price</td>
   </tr>
   }
 </table>

 </body>
```

Here is my Event Controller

```
  public class EventsController : Controller{


    private EventRepository _eventRepository;

    public EventsController()
    {
        this._eventRepository = new EventRepository();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        //return View(db.Events.ToList());
        return View(_eventRepository.GetEvents());
    }

    // GET: Events/Edit/5
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Book(int? id)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("CreateOrder", "Order", new { id = id });

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Book([Bind(Include = "EventID,Name,Location,Date,Description,TicketsAvailable")] Event @event)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Book", "Book", new { id = @event.EventID     });


        }
        return View(@event);
    }

}
}
```

And my ticket order controller

```
   public class OrderController : Controller
   {
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public OrderController()
    {

    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult CreateOrder(int id)
    {
      //  Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
      //  ticket.EventID = id;
      //  ViewBag.EventID = new SelectList(db.Events, "EventID", "Name");
      //  return View(ticket);

        ViewBag.listTickets = (from t in db.Tickets where t.EventID == id  select t).ToList();
        return View();
               }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are following the correct approach except in your booking view:

You are not passing a view model from the action method. So you do not need the `@model Site.Models.Ticket` declaration

In here, you should be looking into `ViewBag.listTickets` instead of `ViewBag.listProducts`.

```
@foreach(Site.Models.Ticket t in ViewBag.listTickets)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @mojorisinify that fixed my problem